# mysql join not returning required result

Tags: mysql, sql

My data looks like the following,

```
employeeId  ManagerId
 3            2
 4            2
 2            1
 5            1
 6            3
```

An employee has a manager and that manager will/could have a manager. What i would like to do is get the manager of an employee and the manager of that manager should it be available.

For e.g. For employee 6 the result will be 3 & 2. For employee 2 it will be 1.

The key requirement here is that the query should return minimum one manager if available and max two levels and no higher. The example given for employee 6 illustrates that.

Right now my query looks like,

```
 select a.managerId firstManager,b.ManagerId secondManager
 from (
 select managerId from Results where employeeId = 6  ) a 
  join 
 (select managerId from Results where employeeId in (select managerId from  Results where employeeId = 6 ) )b ;
```

My query works for employee 6 but not for employee 2. [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c7f65d5d5f7c801e29cee2b4cca7cb5f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below - with recursive cte: **[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=21d15372ede277693bea8cc6a18e8c1d)**

```
with RECURSIVE t as
(
select employeeid,managerid from Results where employeeid=6 
union all
SELECT e.employeeid,e.managerid from Results e inner join t t1 on e.employeeid = t1.managerid
) 
select * from t order by managerid desc limit 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a self join and you will get the results you require. [`dbfiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f569fa7bc30d1623536f4c06a4c616ce)

```
Select a.employeeId,
       a.ManagerId First_Manager, 
       b.ManagerId Second_Manager 
from Results a
left join Results b
on a.ManagerId = b.employeeId
```

**Output:**

```
EmployeeId  First_Manager   Second_Manager
3   2   1
4   2   1
2   1   null
5   1   nul
6   3   2
```

Comment: exactly, self-join is the solution !

Comment: close but if i need results for one employee only. I put *and a.employeeId = 6* it gives the other employees too which i do not need